# ERROR: column "backend_type" does not exist LINE 16: backend_type, ^

Tags: postgresql, macos, pgadmin

I am running PgAdmin4 on macOS and I am trying to connect to a Postgres database (v9.6). When attempting connection, this message is displayed :

> ERROR: column "backend_type" does not exist LINE 16: backend_type, ^

I have absolutely no idea of what this comes from, there is no mention of a column backend_type in my database. Have you ever encountered this problem ?

Comment: From here [Version history](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) Postgres 9.6 is almost 2 years past EOL. From here [pgAdmin 7.5 Release notes](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/7.5/release_notes_7_5.html) *Supported Database Servers PostgreSQL: 11, 12, 13, 14 and 15*. `backend_type` is a column in the system view `pg_stat_activity`  and does not show until Postgres 10.  Use the `psql` client shipped with Postgres.

Answer (score 2):

pgAdmin do not support PostgreSQL 9.6 since long.

Comment: So what is the solution then? @Aditya

Comment: @ShivamSahil You need to upgrade your PostgreSQL server version, or use any other compatible tool.